# Second toolbar in tinymce has "display:none" set?

Tags: tinymce

I have a plugin that inserts a tinymce like shown below. Something causes the second toolbar, the `theme_advanced_buttons2` to have `display:none` attached to their style attribute, effectively hiding them.

I don't manage to find the code responsible for this.

```
$tinymce =  

array
(
      'theme_advanced_buttons1' =>

         '                       \
            ,  undo              \
            ,  redo              \

               ...
               ...

            ,  indent            \
         '

   ,  'theme_advanced_buttons2' =>

         '                       \
               link              \
            ,  unlink            \

               ...
               ...

            ,  help              \
         '
);

wp_editor
(
      $text
   ,  $editor[ 'name' ]
   ,  array
      (
           'tinymce'   => $tinymce
         , 'quicktags' => $enabled
      )
);
```

---

I found the right answer [here](http://wpmu.org/show-the-wordpress-kitchen-sink-options-on-the-editor-by-default/) thanks to a comment by mrwweb:

**Show the Kitchen Sink by Default**

If you would like to show that second row of options by default, there’s an easy way. Simply put the following into your theme’s functions.php file `(Appearance > Edit > Theme Functions – functions.php)`:

```
function unhide_kitchensink( $args )
{
   $args['wordpress_adv_hidden'] = false;
   return $args;
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'unhide_kitchensink' );
```

Comment: Just double-checking. Have you clicked ["Show/Hide Kitchen Sink?"](http://en.support.wordpress.com/visual-editor/#row-2) or hit ALT + SHIFT + Z

Comment: Please post your answer as an Answer below and mark it as accepted when you get the chance.  That way, future visitors can benefit from the solution.

Comment: @EAMann I would if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Show the Kitchen Sink by Default

<sup>Copying [@nus'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/16124/nus) answer as an answer to help newcomers.</sup>

If you would like to show that second row of options by default, there’s an easy way. Simply put the following into your theme’s `functions.php` file:

```
function unhide_kitchensink( $args )
{
   $args['wordpress_adv_hidden'] = false;
   return $args;
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'unhide_kitchensink' );
```

Comment: Is there any easy way to do this conditionally, i.e. not to all instances of the editor? just to instances added with wp_editor() of which we know the id for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `wordpress_adv_hidden=false` anywhere in the tinymce config.

For example,

1. Install this plugin
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-tinymce-configuration/
2. Add an option `wordpress_adv_hidden`
3. With the value `false`

Comment: Without more detail this answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: I dont agree, but I updated the question to be more verbose anyway.

Comment: Hey... @toscho got me for the same thing yesterday :)